# Android app always shows "30 answers" even when there are more

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When there are more than 30 answers, the SE android app displays it as 30. Note the "43 answers" at the top right, and the "30 answers" at the bottom.

[image: screenshot of 30/43 answers]

<sup>v. 0.1.55 on Nexus 7 (2012) on Android 4.3</sup>

Comment: For an added bonus, the application crashes when one attempts to read though all answers. +1.

Answer (score 3):

That was an annoying bug, fixed! Will go out in version 0.1.56 update later tonight.