# Can't view more than 30 answers on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

In the Android app, the "View XX Answers" button displays the correct number of answers, but only the first 30 answers are viewable. For example, on my [Code Golf question here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32757/etaoin-shrdlu-golf), the button says "View 34 Answers" but only the first 30 questions are shown. (Note: this is **not**
 a duplicate of [this bug.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203192/android-app-always-shows-30-answers-even-when-there-are-more))

Comment: guess SE team decided to implement an old feature request [30 answers ought to be enough for anybody](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171063/165773) ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Answer list only displays first 30 answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191524/answer-list-only-displays-first-30-answers): now you can browse [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) and its 350+ answers on SE app!